# how to restore post_excerpt in WordPress template?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I had around 50 articles in my new WordPress theme that showed post-excerpt. I wanted to delete all of them in bulk so I searched for an answer.

I followed a guy which gave this answer:

> Put this in a template file, like index.php, and reload the page:
>
> query( "UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt='' " ); ?>

So I did that and it worked!

But now all of my post_excerpt from the theme got deleted, even the ones I wanted to keep. And even some of the theme got broken.

Please tell me is there any php code to get this back? Maybe to put post_excerpt to show again?

I have tried deleting the code from the index.php and Updating but nothing happens.

Comment: This can't be undone programatically. If your server has any autobackup of database enabled then you can try to restore to previous backup.

Comment: Thanks. Luckily I had backuped the database before this. Is it hard to restore to previous backup? I never did it before.

Comment: your hosting cpanel may have some option to restore to the database or if you simply want the manual way, you can to to your phpmyadmin then select your database and delete all tables( you must delete all existing tables to import your new database) now you can click on import then select your backed up database and import that.

Comment: Thanks Yamu for quick answer! Unfortunately I don't have phpmyadmin details since I am worker for this company. Can this be done via this plugin: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOLfWI3L2v0

If you have time may you have a peak and let me know how thanks!

Comment: Here is my backuped database: https://pasteboard.co/GZn6Zwt.png
And here is how it looks inside of plugin: https://pasteboard.co/GZn7k0j.png

What exactly should I replace, delete and upload?